# SQL: Identifying if a event happened?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, olap, impala

We have a date column like this:

```
Date            Expected Output
1-Jan-18           1
2-Jan-18           0
3-Jan-18           0
4-Jan-18           0
5-Jan-18           0
19-Jan-18          1
20-Jan-18          0
21-Jan-18          0
25-Jan-18          1
29-Jan-18          0
1-Feb-18           0
4-Feb-18           1
13-Feb-18          1
18-Feb-18          1
21-Feb-18          0
3-Mar-18           1
12-Mar-18          1
```

I am trying to write a query in impala/hive, tried to use lead/lag window function was able to find the difference between dates, but facing trouble identifying the events.

Logic : Event will happen obviously on the start date and if any date will be there which lies between start date and start date + 5, then it won't be considered a event. Dates can repeat also, tried to provide some sample data with expected output. Wherever we have 1 in expected column is a Event. My logic doesn't seems to work, tried with case statements and lead/lag window functions.

Comment: Here, please consider start date as start of event date. So from that event start date another event can't happen for next 5 consecutive days. But if we find any other date(viz greater than 5 from last event start date) after our previous event finished, then we will consider that as new event and we have to mark flag. I hope this will further help in understanding more about this problem. Please let me know if any other clarification is required.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired results seem to come from:

```
select t.*,
       (case when date >= lag(date) over (order by date) and
             date < date_add(lag(date) over (order by date), 5)
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: may be I was not able to explain my requirement clearly.., Sorry for that.   Actually, once the event happened, from there for the next 5 consecutive days, same event can't happen. If we get another date after those 5 days that will be our next event. Hope this will help in understanding the requirement further.,  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Your logic is working fine but you are comparing the date with previous date and previous date +5, instead we need to compare date with pervious event start date and previous event start date + 5. We need to modify this lag(dt) over (order by dt) to last date when event occurred.